# Suppose $B$ is a basis for a real vector space $V$. Then, there is a basis for $V$ that is disjoint from $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $B$ is a basis for a real vector space $V$ of dimension greater than $1$. Then, there is a basis for $V$ that is disjoint from $B$.

Can you give a proof for this please?

Comment: Have you tried to formulate a proof yourself? If so where do you get stuck?

Comment: I have no idea how to start the proof... But this is a problem in a GRE 9768 practice exam.

Comment: I don't see why $\dim V > 1$ is there. Start there.

Comment: Hint: if you start with a small linearly independent set and add to it while keeping it linearly independent, eventually it will become a basis.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out Ted. I edited now.

Comment: Hint: Multiply each basis vector by some number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not difficult once you have a good idea. So I'll write a hint, and if you still have difficulties let me know in the comments (but please try for yourself first).

**HINT:** Show that if $\alpha$ is a non-zero scalar, and $B$ is a basis then $\{\alpha v\mid v\in B\}$ is a basis.

Comment: Thank you, @kahen (albeit I generally prefer to be the one who makes these sort of edits myself).

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to consider $V = \Bbb{R}^n$ (why), at least as long as we are in the finite dimensional setting, which I assume.

Use that $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ with $x_i \in \Bbb{R}^n$ is a basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ if and only if $\det(x_1,...,x_n) \neq 0$ (why?).

Then use that the determinant is continuous and that the set $B_\varepsilon (0)$ (i.e. the $\varepsilon$-Ball around the origin in $\Bbb{R}^n$) is infinite (even uncountable) for each $\varepsilon >0$.

EDIT: As Tobias Kildetoft points out, you can also multiply each element of the basis with a suitable real number (you will have to exclude finitely many).

Comment: I don't quite understand the last remark that you make in the parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, I meant finite instead of infinite.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense! :-)